# What hypothesis test should I use to compare the overall performance of two different athletes in a 100m race?

Tags: t-test, chi-squared-test, z-test

I am sourcing data from IAAF's website to test my hypothesis - Athlete A is a better athlete than Athlete B (comparing their times in the Olympics).

Since I would be sourcing the data from IAAF's site, there would be no sampling of data.

I was thinking of using the T-Test, but would another Test - z test, chi squared be more appropriate to use?

Comment: The t-test (or other tests on the mean, depending on assumptions) and Stephan Kolassa's answer are right if both athletes compete in the same disciplines and "better athlete" means "the a athlete that gets a better average mark". However, "better athlete" may mean other things, like "athlete with largest probability of winning a gold medal", "athlete that is more likely go get a highest mark than the other one in a given competition (or in their whole career)", and so. For any definition of "better athlete" a different test may be suitable.

Comment: So would it be safe to define 'better' as the athlete with the smaller (smaller because the smaller the time, the faster he/she ran) mean of times run under 10 seconds? (because 10 seconds or less is considered the Holy grail in major 100m tournaments, and also data isn't available for every time the athlete ever run, especially when they are bad times - for example during the start of the athletes career).

Comment: If you want the athlete with the best recorded mark, you don't need a test: you just need to look at the minimum (or maximum) of each sample. However, if you don't have data for all the career of the athlete, you will need to modelize somehow the distribution of the data you don't have from the data you have. For example, let's say you have record of past achievements for a 20 years old athlete and another 21 years old athlete: to predict which one will get the best mark in the remaining of their careers you need a lot more than a t-test.

Comment: In summary: I suggest clarifying exactly what you want and what data you have, because the answer may be very different depending on that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in mean running times and whether A is faster on average than B, then a t test is exactly what you are looking for.

> Since I would be sourcing the data from IAAF's site, there would be no sampling of data.

That kind of depends on what you consider the base population. I would argue that the more relevant base population is "all of athlete X's 100m race times", including all meets and training, not just the Olympic times. If we go with "my" definition, then your data are indeed a sample.

If you define the base population as including only the Olympic times, then there is no sampling. You have the full population data. But then, you don't need statistical testing any more, because you have the full population. All you need to do is check whose athlete's mean time is smaller.

Comment: Thank you. Just to clarify - your suggestion is to consider all the times each athlete ever run, and use that as my population. And then consider only Olympic times as my sample.

Comment: I agree. One remark is that the data need to be normally distributed to use a t-test. This will probably be the case if your data were collected on a short enough period of time, when the performaces of the athletes have not followed a trend. However, if data were times collected between the age of 10 and the age of 30, then they would not be normally distributed (I guess performance improved from adolescence into adulthood) for each single athlete and a non-parametric test (eg Mann-Whitney) would become more appropriate

Comment: @fabiob: no, the data do not need to be normally distributed to use the t test. (This is a very common misconception.) What is important is that the *sample means* are normally distributed. This is already true for rather small $n$, even if the underlying data are non-normal by the CLT. I agree that covariates should be included if they are important, but then one shouldn't use a nonparametric test without using the covariates; instead, one should build a model including the covariates.

Comment: @Aseda_gh: yes, that is correct.